# ./byfn.sh up -l node failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Hi~ I am playing with the [first-network sample](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html). But when I try to run the command `./byfn.sh up -l node`, I always get the error returned from logs as below.

```
Instantiating chaincode on peer0.org2...
+ peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P 'AND ('\''Org1MSP.peer'\'','\''Org2MSP.peer'\'')'
+ res=1
+ set +x
2020-03-24 08:23:43.975 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2020-03-24 08:23:43.975 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0 for transaction
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

The logs about peer0.org2.example.com docker container:

```
2020-03-24 08:23:19.735 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.4.4
 Commit SHA: 7917a40
 Go version: go1.12.12
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.18
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2020-03-24 08:23:19.740 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2020-03-24 08:23:19.740 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2020-03-24 08:23:19.891 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
2020-03-24 08:23:20.130 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 005 ledger mgmt initialized
2020-03-24 08:23:20.130 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 006 Auto-detected peer address: 172.19.0.6:9051
2020-03-24 08:23:20.130 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 007 Returning peer0.org2.example.com:9051
2020-03-24 08:23:20.131 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 008 Auto-detected peer address: 172.19.0.6:9051
2020-03-24 08:23:20.131 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 009 Returning peer0.org2.example.com:9051
2020-03-24 08:23:20.135 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 00a Starting peer with TLS enabled
2020-03-24 08:23:20.141 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00b Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org2.example.com
2020-03-24 08:23:20.141 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00c Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9052
2020-03-24 08:23:20.145 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 00d system chaincode lscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) registered
2020-03-24 08:23:20.146 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 00e system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
2020-03-24 08:23:20.146 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 00f system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) registered
2020-03-24 08:23:20.146 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 010 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle,true) disabled
2020-03-24 08:23:20.153 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO 011 Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0.org2.example.com:9051 and bootstrap set [peer1.org2.example.com:10051]
2020-03-24 08:23:20.163 UTC [gossip.gossip] NewGossipService -> INFO 012 Creating gossip service with self membership of Endpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, PKI-ID: c4e87a76098ec5decb4b47d1904021bdcea0fbd290f68af4ade352b0b22b0151, Metadata: 
2020-03-24 08:23:20.163 UTC [gossip.gossip] start -> INFO 013 Gossip instance peer0.org2.example.com:9051 started
2020-03-24 08:23:20.164 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 014 system chaincode lscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2020-03-24 08:23:20.165 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 015 Init CSCC
2020-03-24 08:23:20.165 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 016 system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2020-03-24 08:23:20.165 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 017 Init QSCC
2020-03-24 08:23:20.165 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 018 system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed
2020-03-24 08:23:20.165 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 019 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle) disabled
2020-03-24 08:23:20.165 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01a Deployed system chaincodes
2020-03-24 08:23:20.168 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 01b Created with config TLS: true, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000
2020-03-24 08:23:20.168 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 01c Discovery service activated
2020-03-24 08:23:20.168 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01d Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer0.org2.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org2.example.com:9051]
2020-03-24 08:23:20.169 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01e Started peer with ID=[name:"peer0.org2.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org2.example.com:9051]
2020-03-24 08:23:20.169 UTC [nodeCmd] func7 -> INFO 01f Starting profiling server with listenAddress = 0.0.0.0:6060
2020-03-24 08:23:20.169 UTC [kvledger] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 020 Loading prereset height from path [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains]
2020-03-24 08:23:20.169 UTC [fsblkstorage] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 021 Loading Pre-reset heights
2020-03-24 08:23:20.170 UTC [fsblkstorage] preRestHtFiles -> INFO 022 Dir [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains] missing... exiting
2020-03-24 08:23:20.170 UTC [fsblkstorage] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 023 Pre-reset heights loaded
2020-03-24 08:23:21.673 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 024 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:23.673Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:47980 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=101.985µs
2020-03-24 08:23:21.682 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 025 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:31.68Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:47980 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=2.417798ms
2020-03-24 08:23:21.714 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 026 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:23.714Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:47982 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=85.978µs
2020-03-24 08:23:22.955 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 027 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:47982 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error=EOF grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=1.240576335s
2020-03-24 08:23:30.812 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 028 [][28c2fa0d] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc" 
2020-03-24 08:23:30.814 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 029 Creating ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2020-03-24 08:23:30.829 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 02a Getting block information from block storage
2020-03-24 08:23:30.849 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 02b [mychannel] Committed block [0] with 1 transaction(s) in 13ms (state_validation=1ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=7ms state_commit=1ms) commitHash=[]
2020-03-24 08:23:30.851 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 02c Created ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2020-03-24 08:23:30.855 UTC [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 02d Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2020-03-24 08:23:30.855 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 02e No configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
2020-03-24 08:23:30.856 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 02f No configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
2020-03-24 08:23:30.880 UTC [gossip.state] NewGossipStateProvider -> INFO 030 Updating metadata information for channel mychannel, current ledger sequence is at = 0, next expected block is = 1
2020-03-24 08:23:30.883 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 031 system chaincode lscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2020-03-24 08:23:30.883 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 032 Init CSCC
2020-03-24 08:23:30.884 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 033 system chaincode cscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2020-03-24 08:23:30.884 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 034 Init QSCC
2020-03-24 08:23:30.885 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 035 system chaincode qscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed
2020-03-24 08:23:30.885 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 036 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle) disabled
2020-03-24 08:23:30.885 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 037 [][28c2fa0d] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (73ms)
2020-03-24 08:23:30.886 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 038 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.7:53176 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=84.780123ms
2020-03-24 08:23:35.856 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 039 Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer1.org2.example.com:10051]] , current view:  [[peer1.org2.example.com:10051]]
2020-03-24 08:23:40.217 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 03a [mychannel] Received block [1] from buffer
2020-03-24 08:23:40.226 UTC [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 03b Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2020-03-24 08:23:40.226 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 03c Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel : [{peer0.org1.example.com 7051}]
2020-03-24 08:23:40.226 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 03d No configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
2020-03-24 08:23:40.237 UTC [gossip.service] updateEndpoints -> WARN 03e Failed to update ordering service endpoints, due to Channel with mychannel id was not found
2020-03-24 08:23:40.245 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 03f [mychannel] Validated block [1] in 27ms
2020-03-24 08:23:40.285 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 040 [mychannel] Committed block [1] with 1 transaction(s) in 38ms (state_validation=1ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=29ms state_commit=5ms) commitHash=[47dc540c94ceb704a23875c11273e16bb0b8a87aed84de911f2133568115f254]
2020-03-24 08:23:40.563 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 041 [mychannel] Received block [2] from buffer
2020-03-24 08:23:40.571 UTC [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 042 Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2020-03-24 08:23:40.571 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 043 Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel : [{peer0.org1.example.com 7051}]
2020-03-24 08:23:40.571 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 044 Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel : [{peer0.org2.example.com 9051}]
2020-03-24 08:23:40.571 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 045 Anchor peer with same endpoint, skipping connecting to myself
2020-03-24 08:23:40.571 UTC [gossip.service] updateEndpoints -> WARN 046 Failed to update ordering service endpoints, due to Channel with mychannel id was not found
2020-03-24 08:23:40.574 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 047 [mychannel] Validated block [2] in 11ms
2020-03-24 08:23:40.600 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 048 [mychannel] Committed block [2] with 1 transaction(s) in 25ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=18ms state_commit=2ms) commitHash=[5f88b61407b149a48413433f4670c46531e5c4a8febdc339a9536ff8716a559e]
2020-03-24 08:23:40.608 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 049 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:42.607Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.5:53128 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=106.3µs
2020-03-24 08:23:40.622 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04a unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:42.621Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.3:45792 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=94.852µs
2020-03-24 08:23:40.628 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04b unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:42.628Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:48046 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=61.276µs
2020-03-24 08:23:40.631 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04c streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:50.609Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.5:53128 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=21.432415ms
2020-03-24 08:23:40.632 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04d streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:50.624Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.3:45792 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=8.246259ms
2020-03-24 08:23:40.635 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04e streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:50.629Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:48046 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=5.756194ms
2020-03-24 08:23:40.641 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04f unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:42.641Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.3:45798 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=69.002µs
2020-03-24 08:23:40.647 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 050 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:42.647Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.2:48050 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=65.359µs
2020-03-24 08:23:40.658 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 051 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-24T08:23:42.658Z grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.5:53144 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=115.148µs
2020-03-24 08:23:43.862 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 052 [][a8e37e08] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
2020-03-24 08:23:43.863 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 053 Installed Chaincode [mycc] Version [1.0] to peer
2020-03-24 08:23:43.863 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 054 [][a8e37e08] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (1ms)
2020-03-24 08:23:43.863 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 055 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.7:53232 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.77226ms
2020-03-24 08:23:43.977 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 056 [mychannel][1440b726] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
2020-03-24 08:23:45.856 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 057 Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer0.org1.example.com:7051 ] [peer1.org1.example.com:8051 ]] , current view:  [[peer1.org2.example.com:10051] [peer0.org1.example.com:7051 ] [peer1.org1.example.com:8051 ]]
2020-03-24 08:36:47.118 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 058 [mychannel][1440b726] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (783125ms)
2020-03-24 08:36:47.129 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 059 [mychannel][1440b726] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0 for transaction
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:75
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).LaunchInit
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:130
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).ExecuteLegacyInit
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:222
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).ExecuteLegacyInit
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:131
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:183
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:247
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:500
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:169
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/throttle.go:54
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:91
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:30
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:39
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:171
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:982
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1208
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337
2020-03-24 08:36:47.176 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 05a unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.7:53236 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=13m3.203460855s
```

The error I've found from the logs above is:

```
2020-03-24 08:36:47.118 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 058 [mychannel][1440b726] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (783125ms)
2020-03-24 08:36:47.129 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 059 [mychannel][1440b726] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0 for transaction
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch
```

I've searched online many times and get stuck in this error few days. I think is the problem of node or npm and I've also found some useful information from the community of Hyperledger. But I still don't know how to solve this problem. If you have ideas, please give me a hint. Thanks a lot.

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-12318?focusedCommentId=53022&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-53022

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABCN-256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few hints:
Chaincode container startup has a [default timeout of 300s](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-2.0/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L537). If chaincode instantiation takes longer than that (e.g. because you're on a *very* slow network), you'll get a timeout. You can try to extend that timeout by setting `CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT` as env variable on your peer.
To see what is happening during chaincode instantiation, perform a `docker ps`: you'll see some temporary containers running (based on image `fabric-ccenv`). Check their logs using `docker logs`.